# RabbitMQ Authentication and Authorizantion for HTTP publisher

Tags: rest, http, authentication, rabbitmq, authorization

I see that I can publish a message through HTTP using RabbitMQ Manager plugin. My problem is that it exposes the exchanges and operations but requires an administrator user to perform the operations. Is that correct

I tryed to publish to this exchange using a user that I configured with write permission:

http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/%2f/amq.default/publish

And the server returns:

```
{
  "error": "not_authorised",
  "reason": "Not management user"
}
```

But if I try to perform the same operation with the user guest I get the following response:

```
{
  "routed": true
}
```

Is this correct? Do I need to have an administrator user to consume the HTTP publish API (even with a user that has write permissions)? Are there any other options to have an exchanged published accepting requests based on RabbitMQ User permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this feature is part of the management console and exposes functionalities related to this module. There are no options to configure users without administration role and access the HTTP api.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the tag to your user:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl set_user_tags youruser management
```

I got it from [here](https://github.com/MeetMe/newrelic-plugin-agent/issues/147)

Comment: Note to self: creating a new user instead of asking around for the credentials is underrated!